# How to implement a morphtargets human demo use gltf?

Tags: three.js, gltf

Just like https://threejs.org/examples/?q=morph#webgl_morphtargets_human,
but I want to implement a glTF based demo .

I had tried glTF models such as https://github.com/HowardWolosky/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/morphAnimation/2.0/AnimatedMorphCube and https://github.com/HowardWolosky/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/morphAnimation/2.0/AnimatedMorphSphere, but they use animations, I want to control the morph weights manually, like:

mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 0.5;
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[1] = 0;
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[2] = 1;

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to make a glTF file with morph targets? Or you have one, and the control code above isn't working?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I'm the guy who make a pull request yesterday, I had solve this problem, thanks

Comment: Oh hi, great! It might be good to move your code (how to load the glTF, how to change the influences) into your answer below, to help others who find this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had solve this question myself by changing code in gltfloader.js. 
see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11786#issuecomment-316423788

Comment: There are two bugs in three.js's code, after updated to latest code, it works as expected